# Emacs - Projectile Ag. Search specific file types

Tags: emacs

So I am using projectile as project management tool for emacs, and I can do projectile-ag in my emacs to lookup for terms.
I however I would like to filter my search by the file extensions, for instance sometimes I would only like to view terms that matched in .java files and in some cases only the terms matched in .hql files.
How can I achieve it?

(I can probably do it by grepping the ag buffer's results ofcourse - I am looking for a better way to do this - probably something like file masks in Intellij)

Answer (score 2):

If you would use `ag` from the command line you could pass `--java` as a parameter. If you use `ag.el` you would have to call `ag-files` and it will ask you about file type, then just type `java` or `hql`

Answer (score 2):

Using the *universal argument* (`C-u`) before invoking `projectile-ag` (or some other projectile search commands) will present an `args:` prompt, at which you can specify an `ag` option like `--java`.

Comment: I tried `C-u M-x projectile-ag` but I don't see the `args` prompt in Emacs 27.2 +projectile-2.4 + ag.el-0.48.  What did work was providing `C-u g` in the Ag results buffer which allowed me to edit the search command.